# Syntax hilighting does not work in any files in Visual Studio Code on Linux

Tags: visual-studio-code

After upgrading to Ubuntu 20.04 and VSCode 1.45.1, syntax hilighting no longer worked in any files.

There are WebAssembly errors in Output window when I select `Log (Window)` from the channel selector:

```
[2020-05-25 10:02:00.208] [renderer1] [error] WebAssembly.Memory(): could not allocate memory: RangeError: WebAssembly.Memory(): could not allocate memory
    at Object.default (/usr/share/code/resources/app/node_modules.asar/vscode-oniguruma/release/main.js:1:8315)
    at /usr/share/code/resources/app/node_modules.asar/vscode-oniguruma/release/main.js:1:5457
    at Object.t.loadWASM (/usr/share/code/resources/app/node_modules.asar/vscode-oniguruma/release/main.js:1:5685)
    at t._doGetVSCodeOniguruma (file:///usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js:5388:314)
```

My system has 32 gigabytes of memory and is nowhere near the limit.

Answer (score 0):

I had set a virtual memory limit of 10 GB in `.bashrc` using `ulimit -v`, to limit the impact of runaway programs. This worked fine on my previous system that only had 10 GB of RAM.

However the javascript engine used in VSCode apparently allocates virtual memory based on the total RAM size in the system, causing allocation error. Same happens when maximum memory size `ulimit -m` is set.

Returning the limit to default (unlimited) fixed the problem.